# Can I activate an enchantment energy ability during an opponents turn?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

The card in question is [Consulate Surveillance](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bConsulate%20Surveillance%5d), which states: "Pay two energy counters: Prevent all damage that would be dealt to you this turn by a source of your choice."

Can I activate that ability  during my oponents turn? And if so can I do so after he or she attacks or do I have to activate it at the begining of the turn?

Answer (score 10):

You can activate an activated ability at any time that you could cast an instant. This includes on your opponents' turns. Being an energy-related ability has no bearing on this.

There are several different times throughout a turn that each player receives priority, which is when that player can act. In terms of combat, you could activate it either when the combat phase begins, or after your opponent declares his attackers, or after you declare your blockers.

Comment: Thank you so much for clarifying that for me. I couldnt find the answer for it anywhere.

Comment: @user6497504 If this answer satisfied your question, you can click on the check mark to indicate that the answer is "accepted". You can always change your mind and accept a different answer if someone writes a better one.